# eclipselink hints for setter updates

Tags: java, eclipselink, setter, hint

The actual problem I am facing is to be able to force a eclipselink update irrespective of the content of the cache. Currently eclipselink doesn't create new update statements if the new update has the same value as in the cache. I don't want to use the refresh property(`<property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>`
) in the `persistence.xml`.

I am looking for a solution where I can specify to the entity being update not to use the values in the cache.

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();                                        
EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();                                     
                                                                               
t.begin();                                                                     
                                                                               
Ticket ticket = get(ticketId);                                                 
                                                                               
if (ticket == null) {                                                          
    return null;                                                               
}                                                                              
                                                                               
ticket.setState(status);                                                       
                                                                               
em.persist(ticket);                                                            
t.commit();
```

If I change the above update (`setState` method) to a sql query then the query object has an option to do a setHint where we can mention the `setHint(QueryHints.CACHE_USAGE, CacheUsage.DoNotCheckCache)`. I cannot do this either as there are a lot of such updates used.

In the above snippet the update is happening using a setter method, in this scenario how do we specify a hint to ignore cache? Or is there any other way to do the force updates using the setter object?

My problem is similar to this : http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/660750/

Answer (score 0):

The call to `persist` is unnecessary. persist is used to make a transient entity persistent and managed, and your entity is already persistent and managed.

I don't really see the point of an update which would set all the columns of a row to their current value. But if you really want to trigger such an unnecessary update, consider adding a dummy `counter` persistent field and incrementing it. EclipseLink will detect a change from its cached value, and will trigger an update.

Comment: Yeah I have removed the persist call now. The reason I want to update with the same set of values is because there isa possibility for the state field to be manipulated from a different source. In this scenario I want the state field to be updated from the application also. Currently it doesn't happen as eclipselink cache is unaware of the direct changes. Could you give me an example of using a dummy counter?

Comment: @Nizet, was your suggestion to add a new counter in the entity and also a new column in the table? Is there any other solution other than changing the entity ?

Comment: EntityManager em=getEntityManager();
  EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
  
  t.begin();
  
  Ticket ticket = get(ticketId);
  em.refresh(ticket);
  
  if(ticket == null) {
   return null;
  }
  
  ticket.setState(status);
  
  
  t.commit();
  return ticket;
  
  Adding the em.refresh(ticket) works for me now. Are there any disadvantages of using em.refresh(entity) ??
  Is there any other way of using the hints/properties to ensure that a fresh update is done everytime.

Comment: Yes, it was my suggestion. But are you aware that the cache of EclipseLink is a first-level cache, which exists only for the duration of the transaction, and should thus be very small. Even concurrent JPA transactions see a different state of the entity. The fact that some other app writes to the same table should not be a problem. Each time a new transaction starts, the state of the entity is read from the database.

Comment: True, but in my scenario the first transaction is going to be alive when the direct update to the field can happen from other sources (in my case the goldengate mirroring). So if there is a an update from the app again with the same value, the app changes should overwrite the goldengate related changes.

Comment: Unfortunately the refresh also is not the solution. There is a racecondition in my problem.
So 
1 -> First update happens fine for a field to STATE1
2 -> Goldengate tries to update the same field to STATE2, as it tries to replicate the changes from another database.
   There is a timedelay for this replication. But, before the replication happens
3 -> First app fires another update with STATE1. But it is not able to do that because it still sees the value in the database as STATE1, so no new update query is generated.
continue....

Comment: .............                                                      4 -> Then the golden gate allows the STATE 2 update to happen
At step 3 if a force update can be done into the database, then at step4 goldengate will ignore the state2 as it has the old timestamp.
So basically I am looking for a way to generate 2 consecutive update statements from eclipselink even if the value of the field is unchanged.

Comment: Actually the above example looks very confusing. In simple words I am looking to make a force update using eclipselink eventhough the column value is supposdely the same. Currently in this scenario Eclipselink does not generate a Update query, but I am looking to see if there is any configuration changes I can do to make eclipselink generate a UPDATE statement irrespective of the value of the column being the same as the new value or not. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the DescriptorCustomizer I was able to override the update sql generated from the eclipselink. Below is the sample snipppet. But this needs a lot of code changes. If any one of you know a way to do this less intrusively by using some annotations or some configruation file changes please let me know.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;

public class TicketCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer{
     public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {

     String sqlString="update Ticket set DESCRIPTION = #DESCRIPTION, CUSTOMERNAME=#CUSTOMERNAME ,STATE= #STATE where ID = #ID and PRODUCTID= #PRODUCTID" ;

         descriptor.getQueryManager().setUpdateSQLString(sqlString);
        }

}
```

Then define the Customizer for the Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Customizer(com.oracle.ticketsystem.customizer.TicketCustomizer.class)
public class Ticket implements Serializable {......}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to invoke setter with an empty value and invoke setter on the same field again with your expected value. The field will be tracked in Update statement then.